# Continuously showing a pending promise object despite calling the .then syntax and resolving it

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I am just trying to find out what in the world is going on here when trying to resolve the promise. Like my code below, I have been trying to take care and resolve the promise but it is just being a pain at this point even after searching for the answers all over.

```
const getTrades = async () => {
    const accountId = accounts && accounts.find(account => account.type === 'EXCHANGE').id;

    await getTradesInfo({ accountId: quadAccountId });
  };

  const pending = getTrades().then(res => { return res });

  const resolved = pending.then(res => { return res });

  console.log(resolved);
```

So for some reason, the resolved variable above is still showing a pending object.

Comment: Missing `return` keyword in your `getTrades` function?

Comment: To return the value from the "then"... you need to use await... otherwise you will get the promise

Comment: What I can get through this code is: the `then` returns a promise object. If you really want to use `pending`, better to use `const pending = await getTrades().then(res => { return res });`

Comment: `then` does not return the result of the callback - it can't, the callback is invoked later! - but it returns a promise for the result.

Answer (score 0):

your code is still asynchronous, your console log won't wait for your promise to be executed.

here a possible solution:

```
const getTrades = async () => {
    const accountId = accounts && accounts.find(account => account.type === 'EXCHANGE').id;

   return getTradesInfo({ accountId: quadAccountId });
  };

  getTrades.then((res)=> <here can use your console.log> )
```

or wrapping it with async/await:

```
const getTrades = async () => {
  const accountId = accounts && accounts.find(account => account.type === 'EXCHANGE').id;

 return getTradesInfo({ accountId: quadAccountId });
};
(async ()=> {
  const result  = await getTrades();

  console.log(result)
})()
```